# Как поставить composer для нужного пользователя если панель сервера ISPmanager

Tags: ssh, composer

Хочу установить composer для нужного пользователя. Сервером управляет панель ISP manager.

Скачиваю в нужную папку /var/www/test/ все нормально, файл composer.phar появляется.

Обращаюсь в нему через SSH

/opt/php56/bin/php -c /var/www/test/data/php-bin-isp-php56/php.ini /var/www/test/data/composer.phar init

запускает генерацию composer.json

все этапы проходим нормально...

но мне файл composer.json ставится в /root/ папку мне этого не надо!

Так как там php по умолчанию 5.4, а для пользователя test сделан 5.6 который требуют некоторые пакеты...

Как быть? Не знаю возможно ли сменить версию PHP для Root, как я понял ROOT привязан к ISP manager и поменять версию PHP не получится... Могу ошибаться... 
Я новичек в SSH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил сам!

Просто нужно было

1) открыть пользователю Shell доступ
2) в SSH подключиться к пользователю используя команду ssh tets@host и пароль

А дальше уже все по инструкции...

P.S. для установки для других версий php использовал так /opt/php56/bin/php composer install